# retrieve a value from a form from a different html file

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I have an html file in which people fills a form and some queries are done to a database and google maps show locations etc..

What I would need is to save this word in a variable so I can use it in another html. This second html file uses the previous value as a header

So if you type 'metallica' in html file 01, the other file html file 02 should have a header with the value metallica.

So my question is, how do I get values from a form from a different html file?

Rubèn.

Comment: so you are trying to get `metallica` in html file 02? If this is all html then how does the php tag relate? are your file .php or .html?

Comment: I would down vote this question if I could, because the question is not worded well and it shows no signs of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution is to set a session variable. You'll need to submit the form to a PHP file that sets a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['header'] = $_POST['data'];
```

Then you can access it on page 02 like this:

```
echo $_SESSION['header'];
```

Take note that these are simply examples. You'll need to read up on session variables, submitting forms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php then you can save first page value in session and then you can access that value in the next page from session.

Answer (score 0):

you have a number of options.

1. save the value in the session variables, so that you can grab it in page 2
2. send it back to the 2nd through a hidden input field
3. send it through the url (GET)